# What is a watsonrc.wat file in the sharepoint 2007 log folder?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

And how do you open it (if it's a type of log file.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's been written by Dr Watson (part of Windows) but I though that was dead...

Might be best asking this on Server Fault.